# Can I use GitHub GraphQL API from the browser safely?

Tags: github-api, github-api-v4

Can I use [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) from the browser?
In that case, can I set HTTP referrers restriction to prevent abuse?

Comment: **How** do you intend to use GraphQL from the browser. This needs a lot of details.

Comment: @SiKing I would like to search public repositories. And then, I would like to analyze and display search results on the browser.